# Javascript Map/Math/Table

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, sprite, drawimage

OK hello! I'm not the best at math I have a table here. Th

```
    0   0|50   0|100   0|150 0
    0  85|50  85|100  85|150 85
    0 170|50 170|100 170|150 170
    0 255|50 255|100 255|150 255
```

Left is x and right is y, sx and sy for drawImage (Thats the layout for my sprites)
IS there anyway around the giant amount of if statements to control this?

If I am not explain this well enough, the argument sprite is a int 1 to 16 for the amount of animations the sprite has (Its a walking person) so 1 would be idle looking down and 2 would be a walk/step animation and so on each row  down is changed in direction

```
    function sprite(canvas, sprite, frame, x, y){
            var sx, sy = 0, 0
            (insert googleplex of 'if' statments)
            canvas.drawImage(sprite,sx,sy,50,85,x,y,50,85);
    }
```

Comment: You have a fixed size sprite. Indexing into it should be a simple exercise in arithmetic, no `if` statements required.

Comment: Well I guess I could rearrange the sprites then its an easier math problem... Its in a 4x4 grid at the moment no idea how to index that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your sprites are arranged in your image like this:

```
 0  1  2  3
 4  5  6  7 
 8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15
```

You can index them like this:

```
var xpixels = (spriteId%4)*50;
var ypixels = Math.floor(spriteId/4)*85;
```

`x` and `y` offsets are from the top left, so `spriteId = 5` is at `xpixels=50, ypixels=85`.